# Any ideas on How to get the Google Finance Data from iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, google-finance

The Google Finance API only have Java / Javascript. Is there any ideas on getting Google Finance data from iPhone using Objective C? thz u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).  They have a [sample project](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/FinanceSample/) for Google Finance.